# LWJGL - My glsl code somehow does not work

Tags: opengl, java, glsl, lwjgl3

I am following the tutorial "3D Game Development with LWJGL3" using LWJGL 3.0.2(stable)

https://www.gitbook.com/book/lwjglgamedev/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/details

I am following the chapter "Rendering" . Since the vertex.vs and fragment.fs did not work, I tried to compile the shaders using Strings.It was supposed to create a triangle on the screen. However, the result console said it was a problem with some newlines. I am using Eclipse and latest jre and jdk and imported the library through the Build path property.

I am NOT using Maven because there is no Apache Maven installed in my workstation and it is very tedious.

Program Directory:-

> LWJGL
>
> > Engine
> >
> > > GameEngine.java
> > >
> > > Window.java
> > >
> > > Timer.java
> > >
> > > Utils.java(unused)
> > >
> > > IGameLogic(interface).java
> > >
> > > Engine.Graph
> > >
> > > > ShaderProgram.java
> >
> > Game
> >
> > > DummyGame.java
> > >
> > > Renderer.java
> > >
> > > Main.java

Renderer.java

```
package game;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;
import engine.Window;
import engine.Graph.ShaderProgram;
public class Renderer {
 public String fragmentShaderData = 
                        "#version 330                   /n"+ "/n" +   "/n" +                 
                                 "out vec4 fragColor;                                    +
                                 "void main()                    /n"+ "/n" +
                                 "{                        /n"+
                                 "fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);                   /n"+ "/n" +
                                 "}                     /n" +"/n" ;
 public String vertexShaderData = 
 "#version 330   /n"+ "/n"+ 
        "layout (location =0) in vec3 position;      /n"+"/n"+
        "void main()                /n"+"/n"+
        "{                         /n"+"/n"+
        "gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);                   /n"+"/n"+
        "}                           /n"+"/n";

    private int vboId;

 private int vaoId;

 private ShaderProgram shaderProgram;

 public Renderer() {
 }

 public void init() throws Exception {
     shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram();
     shaderProgram.createVertexShader(vertexShaderData);
     shaderProgram.createFragmentShader(fragmentShaderData);
     shaderProgram.link();

     float[] vertices = new float[]{
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
         -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  -0.5f, 0.0f
     };

     FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
     verticesBuffer.put(vertices).flip();

     // Create the VAO and bind to it
     vaoId = glGenVertexArrays();
     glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

     // Create the VBO and bint to it
     vboId = glGenBuffers();
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
     glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
     // Define structure of the data
     glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

     // Unbind the VBO
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

     // Unbind the VAO
     glBindVertexArray(0);
 }

 public void clear() {
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 }

 public void render(Window window) {
     clear();

     if ( window.isResized() ) {
         glViewport(0, 0, window.getWidth(), window.getHeight());
         window.setResized(false);
     }

     shaderProgram.bind();

     // Bind to the VAO
     glBindVertexArray(vaoId);
     glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

     // Draw the vertices
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

     // Restore state
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
     glBindVertexArray(0);

     shaderProgram.unbind();
    }

     public void cleanup() {
     if (shaderProgram != null) {
         shaderProgram.cleanup();
     }

     glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

     // Delete the VBO
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
     glDeleteBuffers(vboId);

     // Delete the VAO
     glBindVertexArray(0);
     glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoId);
 }
}
```

The rest of the code is same as of the sources of this repository:-

[Source code](https://github.com/lwjglgamedev/lwjglbook/tree/master/chapter04)

Except that Utils.java is not used.

The result:

```
java.lang.Exception: Error compiling Shader code: ERROR: 0:1: '#version' :     syntax error
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline

 at engine.Graph.ShaderProgram.createShader(ShaderProgram.java:71)
 at engine.Graph.ShaderProgram.createVertexShader(ShaderProgram.java:37)
 at game.Renderer.init(Renderer.java:64)
 at game.DummyGame.init(DummyGame.java:34)
 at engine.GameEngine.init(GameEngine.java:91)
 at engine.GameEngine.run(GameEngine.java:67)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help!!!!!

There seems to be a problem with my shaders, but I don't know why.

Comment: since the .vs 's don't work in my Utils, I used the direct String method (See Renderer.java)

Comment: since the .vs 's and the .fs  's don't work in my Utils, I used the direct String method (See Renderer.java)

Comment: You are missing a quotation mark on `"out vec4 fragColor;                                    +` aren't you?

Comment: Shouldn't the newline be with a backslash?

Comment: +cozmic  Thanks, it works. Can you post this as answer so that I can set it as resolved?

Comment: +Tyyppi_77 Sorry a little code copy-paste problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newline argument has to be written as \n (with backslash).

Comment: Does he need it, at all? Isn't the shader supposed to compile without them too?

Comment: They are needed because without them the compiler can't know when a #define for example ends and the next line begins. Same goes for #version or basically any preprocessor directive I think. Normal code lines however should compile as expected without newlines as they are terminated by ; unless single line comments are used (//comment).

Comment: I would use them anyways however in case you ever need to print out the shader source to maintain readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String fragmentShaderData = 
                         "#version 330 \n" +               
                          "out vec4 fragColor;" +         
                          "void main(){" +
                            "fragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);" +    
                          "}";
```

is way more readable and should work, too.